# How to compute the variation of the Lagrangian density correctly?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I'm studying Schwinger's action principle in Classical Field Theory, but I have some doubts about the correct variation of the Lagrangian density. Let's consider an infinitesimal transformation of coordinate and fields

$$
x^\mu\rightarrow x'^\mu=x^\mu+\delta x^\mu \\
\phi_s(x)\rightarrow\phi'_s(x')=\phi_s(x)+\delta\phi_s(x)
$$
and we want to know how the action functional $S[\phi]$ varies under this infinitesimal transformation. I have some troubles here, because I have seen lots of different ways to compute the variation of the action (all with the same conclusion of course), but they are in contrast each other "with the math". Since I'm not well versed in this topic, I don't know how to proceed. I tried this way: let's suppose that the Lagrangian density doesn't depend from $x$ directly, then

$$\delta S=\int_{M'}d^4x'\mathcal{L}\left(\phi'_s(x'),\partial'\phi_s'(x')\right)-\int_Md^4x\mathcal{L}(\phi_s(x),\partial\phi_s(x))=\dots$$
since $M$ and $M'$ are different volumes (both have two space-like surfaces as border, spatially infinite) and since the transformation is infinitesimal, we can easily write the Jacobian as

$$J=\det\left(\frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x^\nu}\right)\simeq\det(\delta^\mu_\nu+\partial_\nu\delta x^\mu)=1+\partial_\mu\delta x^\mu \\ \Rightarrow d^4x'=d^4x(1+\partial_\mu\delta x^\mu)$$
then

$$
\dots=\int_Md^4x(1+\partial_\mu\delta x^\mu)\mathcal{L}(\phi_s(x)+\delta\phi_s(x),\partial\phi_s(x)+\delta\partial\phi_s(x))-\int_Md^4x\mathcal{L}(\phi_s(x),\partial\phi_s(x))= \\
=\int_Md^4x\left(\partial_\mu\delta x^\mu\mathcal{L}+\mathcal{L+\dfrac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \phi_s}\delta\phi_s+\dfrac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \partial\phi_s}\delta\partial\phi_s}-\mathcal{L}\right)=\\
=\int_Md^4x\left(\partial_\mu\delta x^\mu\mathcal{L}+\dfrac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \phi_s}\delta\phi_s+\dfrac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \partial\phi_s}\delta\partial\phi_s\right)
$$

which is close to the correct conclusion that I should have, but wrong. The correct one is with the "non local" variation of the fields (someone calls this the total variation, since $\phi'$ and $\phi$ are evaluated in two different geometrical points, the point which has coordinate $x$ before the transformation and the one which has coordinate $x$ after - someone else calls this the shape variation, since it says how $\phi'$ and $\phi$ differ when evaluated in the same value $x$)

$$
\delta_0 \phi_s(x)=\phi_s'(x)-\phi_s(x)
$$

For example, my reference is the book *P. Roman, Introduction to Quantum Field Theory (1969)*, where the author says that the variation of the action, under this infinitesimal transformation, is

$$
\delta S=\int_Md^4x\left(\partial_\mu\delta x^\mu\mathcal{L}+\dfrac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \phi_s}\delta_0\phi_s+\dfrac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \partial\phi_s}\delta_0\partial\phi_s\right)
$$
and he obtains this result because, when it's time to use the infinitesimal Jacobian in the first integral, he automatically changes the variable $x'$ into $x$ inside the fields, completely ignoring the fact that if I want to change a variable inside a definite integral, I have to use the Jacobian for the integration measure AND change the functional form of the integrand, that is

$$
\int_{A'} dx' f(x')=\int_A dx J f(x'(x))\equiv \int_A dx J \bar{f}(x)
$$

What am I wrong?

Comment: Which page in Roman?

Comment: @Qmechanic page 62

Comment: If you need to have variable endpoints (i.e. changing volume in your specific case) then it’s somewhat trickier.